# How to use the electron functions inside of a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, electron

I am using the Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder and whenever I try to include electron ipcRenderer inside of my Vue component using
`import ipcRenderer from 'electron'`
I get this error
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/myname/IdeaProjects/project/node_modules/electron'`

How would i fix this?

Comment: did you installed it `npm i electron`

Comment: Yea i used the vue cli project as a boilerplate. I only cant use electron inside the vue files.

Comment: if you added the plugin with `vue add electron-builder` try running `npm i electron` again. it seems that electron dependencies were not installed.

Comment: I just tried this and it did not fix the problem

Comment: I guess importing the electron module into the renderer cause problems with npm modules that could not be used in browser (like path and fs). Try the approach proposed on electron page with preloading the desired function in `preload.js`. See this [example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#2-expose-ipcrenderersend-via-preload)

Comment: I tried to just import it in the preloader using `import ipcRenderer from 'electron'` but it then ipcRenderer is undefined in the Vue component. Is there anything that I need to do to make it global for the browser window to use?

Comment: the point of `preload.js` is not to expose the `ipcRenderer` to the browser window, but to expose a function that has access to it. by defining a `func` in `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {func: () => ipcRenrerer.send() )` you can access it at `window.electronAPI.func()` anywhere in the app, without the need to expose the `ipcRenderer` to the main world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by adding this to my vue.config.js

```
electronBuilder: {
      preload: 'src/preload.js'
}
```

Then in my browser window I could load a preloader like normal.

Next in my preload i added this

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
```

Now I can use `window.ipcRenderer` in the renderer!